# Emails are not sending (Net::OpenTimeout)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp

I have rails app, on contact us page submit its sending mail.

Its working fine on my local system development and production server too.
But on my VPS its not working

Still its showing `Net::OpenTimeout`

**I have tried**

1) disabling ipv6 using following

```
# /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

2) change port from 587 to 25 and 465

3) also tried to connect smtp from terminal its showing me error

```
root@server1:/var/wwww/test_app# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying port_number...
Trying port_number...
Trying ipv4_address...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested 
        address
```

What is solution for this.

Comment: If you cant connect via `telnet` or other tools, then this is not a Rails question at all, and is a system configuration issue, maybe even specific to your VPS provider (e.g. network or default system firewall rules). Does  `ping smtp.gmail.com` work?

Comment: Okay so how can I solve this system configuration issue?

Comment: @FireLancer `ping smtp.gmail.com` working

Comment: At a guess id say maybe the firewall is restrictive. You will need to find out what firewall software is on the system (default is OS dependent) or if your VPS provider has one at the network level (depending on your provider, contacting them may be easiest if you cant find in support docs). If you can get enough information at least, one of the other sites might be a better place to get help (https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic has some info)